# R - Attempting to Scrape JavaScript rendered table from HTML session without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

I have a tidy HTML page (https://www.ecoccs.com/Surveys_tidy.html) created by converting the raw characters of session_open$response$content, where session_open is the named result of a html_session of https://mics.unicef.org/surveys (after I logged in) made by `rvest`. The tidy HTML page is a JavaScript-less rendition of this HTML page (https://www.ecoccs.com/Surveys-UNICEF-MICS.html).

I have made several attempts at trying to obtain the JavaScript rendered table. I am enclosing just 2 failures below:

```
library("rvest")

withJSs <- xml2::read_html("https://www.ecoccs.com/Surveys_tidy.html") %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@ng-class="countryTree.isFolded"]') %>% rvest::html_text()

withJSs <- xml2::read_html("https://www.ecoccs.com/Surveys_tidy.html") %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@ng-class="countryTree.isFolded"]') %>% rvest::html_text()

> withJSs
character(0)
```

The next step after confirmation of the rendered JavaScript table is to scrape the table contents using PhantomJS.

As the rendered JavaScript table is not available through the tidy HTML page, how can I obtain the contents of the rendered table so that I can use PhantomJS to do the scraping?

Ultimately, I am trying to download the available datasets from the table.

Thank you.

Comment: PhantomJS is dead for 4 years now. Use Selenium, headless Chrome or something like that!

Comment: I've seen (but have not tried or mastered) scraping of js-enabled html tables using `rvest` and the `V8` package.